# Pivot table to Pivot table, by swapping indexes and columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

supposed my dataset

```
Name   Month   Value
A          1     120
A          3     130
A          5     140
B          1     80
B          2     110
B          4     90
C          1     150
C          4     120
C          5     190
D          1     100
D          2     105
....
```

As shown in the data, there are values that do not exist for each month, so first create the first pivot table to fill in the missing values,

```
df_pivot1 = (df.pivot_table(index='Month',columns='Name', values='Value'))
df_pivot1

Name     A    B    C    D
Month
    1  120   80  150  100
    2  Nan  110  Nan  105
    3  130  Nan  Nan  Nan
    4  Nan   90  120  Nan
    5  140  Nan  190  Nan
```

and after filling in missing values(data imputation),

```
Val = Assume that imputation value
Name     A    B    C    D
Month
    1  120   80  150  100
    2  Val  110  Val  105
    3  130  Val  Val  Val
    4  Val   90  120  Val
    5  140  Val  190  Val
```

Now what I want is to use **df_pivot1** so that the index becomes the **Name** and the column becomes the **Month**.

**output what I want**

```
Month  1   2   3   4   5
Name
   A 120 Val 130 Val 140 
   B  80 110 Val  90 Val
   C 150 Val Val 120 190
   D 100 105 Val Val Val
```

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After impute the value try

```
df_pivot1 = df_pivot1.T
```

Comment: I didn't think of the inverse matrix... I was just thinking of changing the code back and forth in a similar answer to this question. Thanks for the simple answer to apply!